# how can i maximally check $_GET,$_POST variables for security issues?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to defend against mysql injection and cross site scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568995/best-way-to-defend-against-mysql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting)
>   [Validating user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638592/validating-user-input)

I know that for mysql I can use >  `mysql_real_escape_string` but what can I use for php server side to maximally secure it from hacking ? Is there any ultimate way to do it ? If not please write all possible ways to minimize threat of hacking the site.

Comment: google it and search similar questions here

Comment: `Security issues` which issues: A: SQL-injection, B: XSS C: something other called...........

Comment: there are many different ways, and I want to gether them together in one function or class maybe. That's why I'm asking

Comment: The variables $_GET and $_POST are not unsafe in any way; the real threat comes from the way you use them. For each method (sql, eval, echo) there is a separate way. So general rules are: sanitize your inputs before you use them and do not trust anyone.

Comment: I am impressed that this question now has four votes to close, each with a different reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way? **Sanitize it when you need it**

Often times I see things like

**Bad code**

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v){
  $_GET[$k] = MyUberSanitizeFunction($v);
}
```

But that works very few times, and is very much type specific (i.e. in one instance an ID may only want to be numbers, but not every value should be stripped of non-numerics).

Worry about cleansing the information when you need it. If you're going to use it multiple times, cleanse it in to a stored variable, then work with it. But don't worry about "mass sanitizing" on every query request.

Comment: +1, was just about to downvote, when I realized the sample is the anti-pattern and not the proposed solution.

Comment: @Johan: Indeed, thanks for the clarity/fix. ;-)